# unix script to add the dynamic attributes in the the yaml file

Tags: shell, unix

I have the below yaml file stored at server on the location `/opt/app/uidai` and the contents of the yaml file named `abc.yaml` is as shown below , as we can see below these data shown is fixed

```
info:
  description : abc
  version: 2.8
  license:
  name: Apache
host:     localhost:8080
basePath: "/"
tags:
- name: abc
  description
```

now in the above yaml file named abc.yaml through unix script i want to add certain atributes at the very top so i want unix script to read this file from   location /opt/app/uidai and add the attibutes at the top so it should look like as shown below , and the data to be add is also fixed , simply i need to add it on the very top as shown below

```
x-google-mamagement
  metrics:
   - name: "abc"
    displayName: "abcd"
  quota:
   limits:
    - name: "abc-limit"
      metric: "ancbg-metric"
info:
  description : abc
  version: 2.8
  license:
  name: Apache
host:     localhost:8080
basePath: "/"
tags:
- name: abc
  description
```

Please advise how to achieve the same

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do you want to add data to files with different content? Is the data to add constant or does it depend on the existing data? If it depends on the existing data, please describe exactly how to derive the required values.

Comment: @Bodo I have added the details and the data that i want to add is fixed just I need to place it on the very top

Comment: Do I understand correct that you have a file `/opt/app/uidai/abc.yaml` that should be modified, and that the resulting modified file should be at the same place? Please clarify this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This script will prepend a fixed text to a file `/opt/app/uidai/abc.yaml` using a temporary file.

```
#! /bin/sh
file=/opt/app/uidai/abc.yaml
temp="$file.tmp"
cat - "$file" > "$temp" << EOF && mv -f "$temp" "$file"
x-google-mamagement
  metrics:
   - name: "abc"
    displayName: "abcd"
  quota:
   limits:
    - name: "abc-limit"
      metric: "ancbg-metric"
EOF
```